# Having troubles with OOP-style Blackjack sim - AttributeError: 'Deck' object has no attribute 'fulldeck'

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to learn the principles of OOP through creating a Blackjack game that someone can play through a cli.

I've successfully set up a full deck of 52 cards with the proper number per suit, but I'm having trouble getting a player's hand.

Code I've written already:

```
import random

class Deck:

    def makeCards(self):
        self.suits = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Hearts']
        self.rank = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']
        for suit in self.suits:
            for rank in self.rank:
                self.fulldeck = (suit, rank)
                self.fulldeck = list(self.fulldeck)
                return(self.fulldeck)

    def playerHand(self):
        self.cardone = random.choice(self.fulldeck)
        self.cardtwo = random.choice(self.fulldeck)
        print(self.cardone, self.cardtwo)

Deck().makeCards()
Deck().playerHand()
```

I'd expect this to output 2 random cards from the cards defined in `self.fulldeck`, but instead it gives me

```
AttributeError: 'Deck' object has no attribute 'fulldeck'
```

I don't get why, as I've defined `self.fulldeck` in the `makeCards` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main part of your issue is that you are calling methods on two separate instances:

```
Deck().makeCards() # create a Deck instance, call makeCards on it, and discard it
Deck().playerHand() # create a new Deck instance, call playerHand on it, and discard it
```

Save a reference to one instance and then reuse it:

```
a = Deck()
a.makeCards()
a.playerHand()
```

I also suspect you will have a problem here:

```
for suit in self.suits:
    for rank in self.rank:
        self.fulldeck = (suit, rank)
        self.fulldeck = list(self.fulldeck)
        return(self.fulldeck)
```

You're iterating through a nested loop, but on every iteration you're reassigning a brand-new `self.fulldeck`, so only the last one will remain. However, the first iteration is the last one, because you `return` on it. When you called this function, you didn't even save it - there's no need to `return` here at all.

You may want something like this instead:

```
self.fulldeck = []
for suit in self.suits:
    for rank in self.rank:
        self.fulldeck.append([suit, rank])
```

You can also refine and fix `playerHand` as follows:

```
def playerHand(self):
    return random.sample(self.fulldeck, 2)
```

Your current version chooses a random card twice, *with replacement*. The card you choose with `random.choice` is not removed from the deck, so you could get the same card twice. Using `random.sample` will return two random cards that are guaranteed not to be the same card. You can do whatever you like with these cards, such as print them (`print(a.playerHand())`).